# How do I connect to OCI using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm having fun and games connecting to OCI using the Terraform OCI provider from https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci

My failing connection terraform is:

```
provider "oci" {
  tenancy_ocid         = var.tenancy_ocid
  user_ocid            = var.user_ocid
  fingerprint          = var.fingerprint
  private_key_path     = var.private_key_path
  private_key_password = var.private_key_password
  region               = var.region
}
```

with a corresponding pem file referenced in my var.tf of:

```
variable "private_key_path" {
  type    = string
  default = "~/.oci/oci_api_key.pem"
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: can not create client, bad configuration: did not find a proper configuration for private key
```

I'm following this to setup the right credentials: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks to John Hanley I modified my var.tf to the following at it worked!  Note the change from `~/.oci` to a full path of `/Users/jnevill/.oci`.  This was on Macos using brew installed terraform.

```
variable "private_key_path" {
  type    = string
  default = "/Users/jnevill/.oci/oci_api_key.pem"
}
```

Comment: 1) Do you have `~/.oci/config` setup correctly? If yes, then you do not need to define the variable. 2) The `~` character is a shell concept. Try changing to an absolute path like `/home/<username>/.oci/oci_api_key.pem`. 3) Everything else looks OK. 4) Update your question with the OS distribution and the shell that you are using for future reference.

Comment: @JohnHanley that worked, thankyou!  Yes, replacing the tilda with the absolute path fixed the issue.

Comment: Post an answer with the changes. This will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thankfully a simple solution to this one - thanks to John Hanley pointing me in the right direction.  In short the `~` wasn't working in the private_key_path variable.

**Solution**

Change the pem reference from `~` to `/Users/YourUserName/`

This enables terraform to reference the pem file correctly.

**Failing var**

```
variable "private_key_path" {
  type    = string
  default = "~/.oci/oci_api_key.pem"
}
```

**Working var**

```
variable "private_key_path" {
  type    = string
  default = "/Users/jnevill/.oci/oci_api_key.pem"
}
```